# Javascript - how to show DIV after putting text into <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write function in JavaScript  which will show/hide 'DIV' after putting some text into .

I managed to write it, however I cannot to make it work only if user put to the 'input' value bigger than 8.

**Html:**

```
<input type='text' id='area' style='border: 1px solid;'></input><br>
<div id='text1' style='display:none; '>Examletext</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#area").keyup(function() {
        if ($('#text1').is(":hidden")) {
            $('#text1').show(500);
        } else {
            $("#text1").hide(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Above is working script, but this works whatever you put into the 'input'. I want execute the script only when I put value bigger than 8 (9, 10, 101 etc.)

I tried to add this(no effect):

```
if ($("#area").value > 8){}
```

Here is the working script where I have commented out line described above - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVW3u/)

Comment: I would strongly recommend doing some research into the differences between java and javascript

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the tip:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `$("#area").value` to `$("#area").val()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#area").keyup(function() {
        if ($("#area").val() > 8) {
            if ($('#text1').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#text1').show(500);]
            } else {
                $("#text1").hide(500);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In jQuery you need to use `val()` not `value`

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/tVW3u/3/)

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Thanks, it is working pretty nice. I just need to add some code so the ‘div’ will disappear when putted value will be less/ or equal 8. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

It's not .value but val()

Your jsfiddle should be

```
if ($("#area").val().length > 0){
```

Comment: Thanks - this was the issue

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#area").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#area").val() > 8){
        if ($('#text1').is(":hidden")) {
            $('#text1').show(500);
        } else {
            $("#text1").hide(500);
        }
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#area").keyup(function() {
        if ($("#area").val() > 8) {
             $('#text1').toggle("slow");
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

parse the value to int before comparison and use val instead of value

```
if (parseInt($("#area").val()) > 8){
 //write the action to be performed here
}
```